# Using localizable.strings on storyboard

Tags: xcode, localizable.strings

Rather new to Objective C here... Is there any way to load localizable strings directly into the storyboard and use their values there *without* doing it through code? (e.g. set up a label's text using a localizable string on the storyboard itself, rather than define that label in code and setting it up there?)

Comment: You can localise the entire storyboard if thats what you want.

Comment: i think its not possible... you must set it programmatically

Comment: I think you must have the newest Xcode to do that.